# access array number 2 and 3 to be in one string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

How to have output :

```
ID: 0001
Name: Mike
Birthday: London 21/05/1989
Hobby: Reading
```

My below code is undefined, I want the array city + date to be together in the birthday.

My code was not, check my code below :

```js
var input = [
                ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
                ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
            ];

var data = ["ID: ", "Name: ", "Birthday: ", "Hobby: "];




for(var i = 0 ; i <= input.length ; i++){
  for(var j = 0  ; j <= input.length ; j++){
  for(var i = 0 ; i <= data.length; i++){
  console.log(data[i] + input[j][i])
    };
  };
};
```

Is that any suggestion to fix this logic ? I just  want to use the loop, for this.

Comment: the sample output on the top , @Rai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the index in array is 0 based AND `i=0` you have to change

```
i <= input.length
```

To

```
i < input.length
```

```js
//contoh input
var input = [
    ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
    ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
    ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
    ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
];

var data = ["ID: ", "Name: ", "Birthday: ", "Hobby: "];

for(var i = 0 ; i < input.length ; i++){
  for(var j = 0  ; j < input.length ; j++){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
      if(i == 2)
        console.log(data[i] + input[j][i] +' '+ input[j][i+1])
      else if(i == 3)
        console.log(data[i] + input[j][i+1])
      else
        console.log(data[i] + input[j][i])
    };
    console.log('=================')
  };
};
```

Comment: on that code , your  hobby  is : date,
i want the birthday : city + date in array

Comment: you are rock, perfect;

Comment: @ZrClassic, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var input = [
                ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
                ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
            ];
            
var expectedOutput = input.map(a=>{
 return {ID:a[0],Name:a[1],Birthday:a[2] + ' ' + a[3],Hobby:a[4]}
})

console.log('string output',JSON.stringify(expectedOutput));
console.log(expectedOutput);
```

Comment: well map is magic, how about if we use loop for it ?? and the output must be string @justcode

Comment: @ZrClassic You can check my updated answer, and map is indeed loop. you can use other loops too like reduce, foreach etc. this is just a one example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
//contoh input
var input = [
                ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
                ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
            ];

var data = ["ID: ", "Name: ", "Birthday: ", "Hobby: "];

// for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
//   console.log(data[i]);

var k = 0;
for(var i = 0 ; i < input.length ; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j <= data.length ; j++){
       if(j == 2 ){
          console.log(data[k] + input[i][j]+ " " + input[i][j+1]);
          j++;
       }
       else
          console.log(data[k] + input[i][j]);
       k++;
   }k=0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let output = input.map( item => {
return ({ID:item[0],name:item[1],birthDay:item[2]+item[3],hobby:item[4]})
})
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = [
                ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
                ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
            ];
            
let output= input.map(([ID, Name, Country, DOB, Hobby]) =>{
    return({
      ID, 
      Name, 
      Birthday: `${Country} ${DOB}`, 
      Hobby
    })
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Just check for the necessary conditions before printing. 
and also check for printing the values of array which are being pointed by indexes which are out of bound. That is why it showed undefined.

```js
var input = [
  ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
  ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
  ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
  ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
];

var data = ["ID: ", "Name: ", "Birthday: ", "Hobby: "];

for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input[j].length; i++) {
    if (i === 2)
      console.log(data[i] + input[j][i] + " " + input[j][i + 1]);
    else if (i === 3)
      console.log(data[i] + input[j][i+1]);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can merge  city + date in `input` array first, then looping will be more easier

```
var expectedOutput = input.map(a=>{
 return [a[0], a[1], a[2]+' '+a[3], a[4]]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using native *ForLoop* and in **one** loop you can do :

```js
//contoh input
var input = [
                ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
                ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
            ];

var data = ["ID: ", "Name: ", "Birthday: ", "Hobby: "];

for(var i = 0 ; input[i] && input[i].length ? i < input[i].length : null ; i++) {
  console.log(data[0] + input[i][0]+ ',', data[1] + input[i][1]+ ',', data[2]+input[i][2] + ' '+ input[i][3]+ ',', data[3]+ input[i][4]);
};
```

**PS:** *It is more elegant to use ES6 operators such as map and forEach..*

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the variable name in the third "for" statement. I didn't take a very deep look into the loops, but I believe you do not want to use the variable "i" in the 3rd loop. Try naming it "var k"

Comment: i did that, it makes the words messy LOL

Answer (score 0):

```js
//contoh input
var input = [
                ["0001", "Mike", "London", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Sara", "Manchester", "10/10/1992", "Swimming"],
                ["0003", "John", "Kansas", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Dave", "Nevada", "6/4/1970", "going to gym"]
            ];

var data = ["ID: ", "Name: ", "Birthday: ", "Hobby: "];

// for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
//   console.log(data[i]);


  var check = 0;
  for(var j = 0  ; j < input.length ; j++){
  var count = 0;
  outerloop:
  
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
  if(count==2){
    console.log(data[i] + input[j][i] +' '+ input[j][i+1]);
  count = 0;
  check = 1;
    continue outerloop;
  } if(check==1){
    count++;
     console.log(data[i] + input[j][i+1]);
    check = 0; 

}
else{
    count++;
     console.log(data[i] + input[j][i]);
  }
    };
  };
```

**Brief:**
i have used one `if condition`  and 1 `ifelse condition`, and used 2 variables for both conditions, 1st variable in only if condition is count variable which checks if the index is of birthday, if yes then concatenate the current value and it's adjacent value, and then i used one check variable which will be true in that if condition and we will continue the loop without going deep in that iteration. the check variable is used just to identify a normal iteration which you implemented when check is 0 and if it's 1 then the adjacent index will be showed. hope it will help you.

Comment: thx for your explanation, I still trying to understand the logic of your codes :)